# InvalidProtocolBufferException when trying to compile Bazel on 32bit Linux Mint

Tags: python, tensorflow, out-of-memory, bazel, linux-mint

I am trying to compile Bazel-0-19.2 on 32bit Linux Mint so that I can install tensorflow on the machine, but when trying to compile Bazel I always get the exception google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException and

> ERROR:
> /home/laxle/Bazel-0-19.2/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/skyframe/serialization/BUILD:11:1:Building src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/skyframeserialization/libserialization.jar (53 source files) failed: Worker process  returned an unparseable WorkResponse!

and

> Internal Error (g1ConcurrentMark.cpp:1667), pid=375, tid=382

> fatal error: Overflow during reference processing, can not continue. Please increase MarkStackSizeMax (current value: 2097152) and restart.

I tried export BAZEL_JAVAC_OPTS="-J-Xmx1g" and BAZEL_JAVAC_OPTS="-J-Xms384m -J-Xmx512m" in the terminal before running the compile command but neither solved the issue.  Is there something I can do to either get Bazel to install or another way to run tensorflow on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow is tested and supported on the following 64-bit systems:

```
Python 3.6–3.9
Ubuntu 16.04 or later
Windows 7 or later (with C++ redistributable)
macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (no GPU support)
```

Follow the instructions mentioned on [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) to build Tensorflow from source using Bazel